# Почему исключение можно принимать по ссылке

Tags: c++

Почему объект передаваемый в исключении может приниматься по ссылке, хотя он должен только копироваться, то есть при раскрутке стека он копируется из одной области видимости в другую

Comment: "...то есть при раскрутке стека он копируется из одной области видимости в другую" - кто вам такое сказал? Ничего подобного не происходит. Это во-первых. А во-вторых, даже если бы это было и так, то все равно - где здесь проблема с приемом по ссылке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При выбрасывании исключения оно копируется в специальную область памяти для хранения исключений (или, по возможности, сразу создается в этой области). Поэтому перехватывая исключение по ссылке вы получаете ссылку на этот объект, а не на некоторый объект, который раньше был на стеке. При этом перехватывание исключения по ссылки является предпочтительным в плане производительности по сравнению с перехватыванием по значению, так как в этом случае не происходит копирования.

Comment: Ещё и срезка может произойти при перехвате по значению.

Comment: Справедливо ли это для любых типов бросаемых объектов исключений или же только для унаследованных от std::exception? Т.е. если я бросаю string/int/double/custom class, то объект также будет создан в этой области?

Comment: @goldstar_labs Да, они всегда попадают в некоторую специальную область.

Comment: @goldstar_labs `std::exception` — обычный библиотечный тип, не обладающий никакой магией.

Answer (score 0):

ССылька подразумевает, что может обрабатываться обьект этого класса или любого производного класса. Она дает возможность также не копировать обьект во второй раз.

Обьект простых типов, имеющие представление в размере одного машинного   слова и не имеющих производных классов, можно принимать и по значению. По  значению нужно принимать также в случаи, если вы хотите исключить возможность обработки обьекта любого производного класса...